# Sum of series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm sure that this sum we should calculate with telescoping, but what algebraic conversions I must do?   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$$

Comment: $$\dfrac1{n!(n+2)}=\dfrac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=\dfrac{n+2-1}{(n+2)!}=?$$

Comment: oh, thank you, I should have noticed this conversion :)